# Why are Saudi men forbidden from marrying citizens of Chad, Myanmar, Bangladesh or Pakistan?

Tags: marriage, saudi-arabia

Apparently these four countries are singled out in the law. What is specially significant about these four countries in relation to Saudi Arabia and specifically its Marriage laws?

The claim is made in a recent [answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/91266/48046)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the law, please.

Comment: Questions about why a country has chosen to adopt policies embodied in a law is the way that it is are really for Politics.SE rather than Law.SE. This is perhaps particularly true in Saudi Arabia, which as an absolute monarchy doesn't have a transparent legislative process whose legislative history is available.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Politics.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia article I cited in the original answer, the reasoning for these countries is that Saudi Arabia has a high population of immigrants from those nations and prefers not to allow further immigrants entry through marriage.